# Python Selenium select only one item in a listbox

Tags: python, selenium, listbox, webdriver, scrapy

`ListBox` (not a drop downlist) as follows:

```
<select name="lstym" onChange="SubmitForm(this.form,'ym')" multiple size="5">
    <option value="All" selected>All</option>
    <option value="201601">201601</option>
    <option value="201602">201602</option>
    <option value="201603">201603</option>
    <option value="201604">201604</option>
    <option value="201605">201605</option>
 </select>
```

Scrapy code:

```
 select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('lstym'))
 for option in select.options:
     #select.deselect_all()
     #select.deselect_by_index(0)
     option.click()
```

The first item defaultly selected is always selected too. But want to select only one item once.
`select.deselect_all()` and `select.deselect_by_index(0)` are not working.

**Solution (not good) I found:**

```
  browser.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="lstym"]').click()
  browser.find_element_by_xpath('//option[@value="201601"]').click()
```

At least the default selected item `All` was removed. But the third item is always selected. This is OK for me.

Comment: Does this behavior also occur when you select manually?

Comment: No. It is in scrapy code like that. No any problem if select manually.

Comment: So just to double check, when you select other options, ALL remains selected?

Comment: Only wanted one was selected if select manually without pressing Ctrl or Shift key. But in scrapy code always two items were selected (the first one always selected).

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you select one element in a listbox, the other elements are deselected. So you should be able to just click the element you want, and it will deselect all the other options.

Comment: Should be like that. But selenium seems not working that way.